# openSSL 1.1.1 security bug CVE-2020-1971

Tags: updates, openssl

I just read a description of CVE-2020-1971, which indicates that a patch was released today for openSSL, the patched version is 1.1.1i -- my version of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS is running openSSL version 1.1.1f.  From last March.

Software Updater says that my system is up to date.  I am hoping that this openSSL update is released by Canonical by tomorrow... can anyone confirm they are working on this?

Comment: Also related: [How do I update apache2 to the latest version on Debian jessie?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404117/109651)

Comment: Related: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#Versions https://www.debian.org/security/faq#version https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/html/SLES-all/cha-update-backport.html

Comment: I think the key is to run `apt update` before listing available versions with `apt list` or trying an upgrade with `apt install`. In this particular case:
`apt list openssl --installed` returns: 
`openssl/now 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,local]`
while 
`apt update && apt list openssl --installed` returns: 
`openssl/focal,now 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**When a CVE question comes up, your first stop should be Ubuntu's CVE tracker at https://ubuntu.com/security**.

1. Here's what the Ubuntu CVE tracker said about [this CVE](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2020-1971) and this package when I checked:

   [image]

   - According to https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2020-1971, this CVE was mitigated in 20.04 in `openssl 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1`, which is **already** in the Ubuntu repositories (focal-security pocket).
2. Let's double-check that `openssl 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1` is available for apt to download and install:

   ```
   $ apt-cache madison openssl   // 20.04 system, matching the question
   openssl | 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2          | focal 
   openssl | 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1        | focal-security  <----- There it is
   openssl | 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1        | focal-updates   <----- And there, too
   ```
3. For the curious, let's take a look at the [Launchpad page for that package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl) to determine the patched 20.04 version's upload date (08 December 2020 / 08.12.2020) :

   [image]
4. Check your installed package version using `apt list openssl`.

   ```
   $ apt list openssl
   Listing... Done
   openssl/focal-updates,focal-security, now 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
   ```

   - For most users, Unattended Upgrades has already downloaded and installed many -security upgrades like this automatically and silently. Rapidly rolling out security patches without pestering you is exactly what it is intended for.

---

Background: There are two ways to handle security updates.

1. Update to a newer release that incorporates the change. Since most users have no idea how to apply a patch, this is a common recommendation. For unskilled users, this is an easy and reasonably safe method. This will update you to 1.1.1i
2. Apply the patch to the current version. Since the Ubuntu Security Team engineers DO know how to apply and test patches, this is how Ubuntu security updates work. Ubuntu provides a *patched* version, not a *new* version. This will update you from 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2 to 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1. Yes, your -v flag will say 1.1.1f, and that's correct. But you are still patched; the vuln can no longer affect you.

Comment: `apt changelog openssl` also shows the patch added.